# Is there a variable evaluator in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a JSON object as a configuration file with strings. These strings represent attributes of an object.

How can I interpret strings of the format `json.id.value` by a function as variables or references?

I have seen the [eval crate](https://crates.io/crates/eval), but I don't think it is what I need.

Comment: If you know the layout of the JSON object beforehand, you could probably use a JSON deserializer or map the values manually to a struct.

Comment: Please see my comment below.

Comment: Or lets describe it differently: can i run rust code from a string? Can i inject code to be run from a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust is a compiled language. What you want isn't directly possible, because names don't exist in the compiled code anymore.

But if you want to go from JSON to Rust structs, that's what the serialization library [Serde](https://serde.rs/) is for.

Comment: I am already using serde for creating the json objects, one conf file and one data file but the data file has like 250 attributes. So if I want to add values to the config file i later than have to handle these values with if else or whatever each one individually in pseudocode: if string is "json.id.value" {a = json.id.value;}

Comment: @KilianHertel Are you using serde or serde_json?

Comment: i am using both

Comment: `serde_json` provides you with a `json!` macro. Why are you parsing the string manually in your `if` condition instead of using said macro?

Comment: ah ok so you can load the big json with json! and then access the attributes with the [""] like json["id"]["value"]. Thank You! I think i gonna try that!

Comment: @KilianHertel I am really confused by your description. Can you maybe edit your question to show the code you're writing now and the code you want to write?